# PHP using ssh2_exec to execute script with parameters from query

Tags: php, ssh2-exec

I am trying to execute a script from a server, the parameter is retrieved from MySQL query and stored into `$test` is there a way to use this as a parameter for my script? I have a script stored in a parameter as well `$script`

```
<?php

include("db.php");  
$user = 'user';
$password = 'pwd';

$script = '/my/path/to/script/script.sh';

...

$testResult = mysqli_query($dbConnection, $queryNextTest);
$test = $testResult->fetch_object()->test_script; //this is my parameter obtained from query

$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $script); //how can I use test as my paramter to execute the 

?>
```

So what I am looking for is something like this: `$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, '/my/path/to/script/script.sh $test');` but the `$test` cannot be inside the quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the quote to double and use curly bracket to express your variable like this:

```
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, "{$script} {$test}");
```

Or even without curly braces like this:

```
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, "$script $test");
```

Comment: Am I allowed to combine two variables like this? `$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, "{$script} {$test}");`

Comment: Yes, definitely.

Comment: One more question, is it always good to use double quotes? What are the advantages from double quotes to single quotes and vice versa?

Comment: No, you each one has its pros and cons in certain cases. You can refer this link for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php